# Sinusoidal projection

Tags: geometry, cartography

We have a sinusoidal projection that takes a point of longitude θ and latitude φ on earth and projects it to the point ( x , y ) = (Rθ cos(φ), Rφ) on a 2 dimensional map.

What would be the image of a meridian and of a parallel with this transformation
(here R would be the radius of the earth)

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you run into problems?

Comment: Usually we are asked for a more general solution to the problem so i am not quite sure what coordinates to use for my meridians and parallels